# Dynamic Element not responding to .Live() function

Tags: jquery, bind, live

I have a script that generates a list of elements; spans. I have scripts that move them around in the DOM hierarchy, to target divs and such, using .appendTo(). This following script won't work on the newly moved object, even though I'm using .live().

```
    var User = 0;
    $(".List span").live('dblclick', function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
        User = $(this).attr('class').match(/Usr1/g) ? 1
             : $(this).attr('class').match(/Usr2/g) ? 2
             : null;
        $(this).prependTo("#List_" + User); 
    });
```

To clarify: I click a span; it moves to .List. I dblclick the span in .List; nothing happens. It should move to #List_*. The spans already in .List do move if I dblclick them.

Why doesn't the new guy move?

Comment: FYI, `.live()` has been deprecated in favor of `.delegate()` or `.on()`, depending on your jQuery version.  Is the problem that the span is never removed from .List, is never added to #List_, or both?

Comment: Finally, have you double checked that the spans arrive into .List looking like you expect (ie, not wrapped in a div or somesuch)?

Comment: I'd recommend either stepping through your code with a good in-browser debugger (pro-tip: chrome, safari and (recent versions of) firefox and opera all ship with amazing debugging tools). Barring that, create a jsfiddle example of your js + html and post that for people to look at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reformulated the problem script, and it all works now. Thanks for letting me know about .on(), I'll look into it.